# How to assign RBAC for ARM to Managed Identity

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-managed-identity

An app needs to list RBAC role assignment for a given ressource. This works locally using my own credentials (`AzureCliCredential`), but not when deployed in Azure using `ManagedIdentityCredential`. I suppose this is because I am the subscription owner.

How would I authorize the MSI to have read/list permissions with regards to the ARM itself?

The following code is used.

```cs
    public static async Task<RoleAssignmentsResult> GetRoleAssignmentsFor(string resource)
    {
        const string VERSION = "2018-01-01-preview";
        string url = $"https://management.azure.com/{resource}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?$filter=atScope()&api-version={VERSION}";
        Stream respBody = await _request(url);
        var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<RoleAssignmentsResult>(respBody);
        return result;
    }

    private static async Task<Stream> _request(string url)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage req = new(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(url));
        
        string[] scopes = { "https://management.azure.com" };
        ManagedIdentityCredential cred = new();
        TokenRequestContext ctx = new(scopes);
        return await cred.GetTokenAsync(ctx);

        req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwt.Token);
        HttpResponseMessage res = await new HttpClient.SendAsync(req);
        return await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I think the Managed Identity needs a Reader role. Try assigning it the Reader role on the resource.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, the resource would be the subscription, right?

Comment: You should be able to set it at resource/resource group/subscription level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @juunas. As you proposed in the comments to the question, assigning the `Reader` role for the resource to the MSI did the trick. As I was interested in listing role assignments for individual KeyVault secrets, I chose the vault as the scope.